# EF5 automatically sort navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, navigation-properties

I have a class structure which is used by Entity Framework (code-first);

```
public class Product
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

The `Image` class has an `Order` field, which can essentially handle sorting. At some point in my application I write a line such as;

```
BindImages(product.Images);
```

What I would like is for the `Images` to be automatically sorted by the `Order` field when I request a `product.Images`, without me having to write `product.Images.OrderBy(x => x.Order)` everywhere.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF cannot do for you what you want. But you can do this. You can add to your type another property

```
public IEnumerable<Image> OrderedImages
{
   get{return Images.OrderBy(x => x.Order); }
}
```

and use it instead previous collection.

Comment: Just to point out, you may need to add the `[NotMapped]` attribute to stop EF complaining about changes.